# Mysql - Valid Unique E-mail

Tags: mysql

I want to get the total number of all valid e-mail address in a database, but I also want the total to be unique e-mail addresses. Is this possible with mysql alone?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this maybe?

```
SELECT `email`
FROM `users`
WHERE `email`
REGEXP '[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}'
GROUP BY `email`
```

Regex was from [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/email.html). As the site points out, this may not match all valid emails (i.e. the obscure ones). The last time I looked into it I'm not sure if anyone had created a regular expression which would match every possible email address.

Comment: If you're going to use a regular expression, why not use the full on provided on the same page? (?:[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*|"(?:[\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x21\x23-\x5b\x5d-\x7f]|\\[\x01-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x7f])*")@(?:(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?|\[(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.){3}(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?|[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9]:(?:[\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x21-\x5a\x53-\x7f]|\\[\x01-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x7f])+)\])

Comment: thats still not the full one, the full one is 6300+ characters long

Comment: This is perfect, I didn't really think of regex. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can't check if an e-mail is valid with mysql.

You can select all unique e-mail with a distinct select:

```
SELECT DISTINCT `e-mailadress`FROM `table1` //something like this
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want the number of them you'd do

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT('EMAIL')) FROM 'TABLE'
```

Comment: I do actually need to know if they're valid in this case.